# Linux / Proxmox KVM machine boots unreliable after migrating to other server

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, proxmox

I have a KVM VM running on a Proxmox 2.3 server. The Guest OS inside the KVM machine is an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit. I took a consistent backup of the VM (Proxmox VE backup function) and restored the VM on a new Proxmox VE 4.1 server.

If I start the VM, it does something strange:

- Sometimes, it just boots as expected and seems to run as expected.
- Sometimes, it hangs at boot. The last operation I can see is an ext4 filesystem check which tells me that everything is clean.
  [image]

I can press enter on the console and I can see new lines. So it does not hang completely, but I am not able to spawn new tty's to examine the issue.

Any Idea how to debug and resolve the problem?

Comment: Try powering off the VM before migrating it.

Comment: The migration was done offline as the servers do not share anything, not even a backup space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the unreliable boot process: Quotas. I already thought about quotas, but even checking or repairing quota files was't a solution.

When I deleted /etc/init.d/quota and /etc/init.d/quotarpc, the boot process was normal and now the machine boots.